# In what situations would findViewById suddenly return null?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a `Fragment` I'm using `ExoPlayer` in with its own `PlayerView`, hosted by an `Activity` that has a popup 'dialog' view with another `PlayerView` that I intend to share an `ExoPlayerInstance` with. Both `PlayerView`s are declared in the layout XML.

The Player itself is declared in the `Fragment`.

When the `Activity`'s `PlayerView` borrows the `Fragment`'s, the Player object is transferred just fine. However, when the `Activity` returns the Player object to the `Fragment`, for some reason the `PlayerView` in the `Fragment` is null.

I know I could just do a null check on the `PlayerView`, but that might not solve the root cause - the reason why findViewById of a `Fragment` suddenly returns null.

So, how does that happen, and how do I work to solve, or work around, it?

EDIT:

The code I use to borrow/return the Player object in the Fragment:

```
fun borrowPlayer(): SimpleExoPlayer {
    vw_exo_player.player = null
    vw_exo_player.fadeInvisible(100)
    return player
}

fun returnPlayer() {
    if(vw_exo_player != null) {
        vw_exo_player.player = player
        vw_exo_player.fadeVisible(100)
    }
}
```

The fragment's XML is basically as follows:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    ...
    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/vw_exo_player"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:resize_mode="zoom"
        app:surface_type="texture_view"
        app:use_controller="false"
        tools:visibility="invisible" />
    ...
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As seen here, the Fragment's layout XML has that view ID'd `vw_exo_player`.

The two functions above are called in the Activity:

```
fun showPopupVideo(anchor: PopupVideoAnchor) {
    if (popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.isOn == true) return

    if (anchor == PopupVideoAnchor.WEB && (popupVideoHolders[PopupVideoAnchor.QNA]?.isOn == true || popupVideoHolders[PopupVideoAnchor.POLL]?.isOn == true)) {
        return
    }

    Trace.i("Show Popup : $anchor")

    if (pv_popup.player == null) {
        pv_popup.player = findFragment(GameAVStreamFragment::class.java)?.borrowPlayer()
    }

    val x: Float = popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.x ?: 0F
    val y: Float = popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.y ?: 0F
    val w: Int = popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.w ?: 0
    val h: Int = ((w.f / videoSize.w.f) * videoSize.h.f).i
    val b: Float = if (popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.isBordered == true) 0.95F else 1F
    val layoutParam = lay_popup_video.layoutParams

    for (popupVideoHolder in popupVideoHolders) {
        if (popupVideoHolder.value.isOn) {

            loadAnimation(R.anim.fade_out).apply {
                duration = 150
                onEnd {
                    lay_popup_video.clipScale = 1F
                    lay_popup_video.x = x
                    lay_popup_video.y = y
                    lay_popup_video.layoutParams.width = w
                    lay_popup_video.layoutParams.height = h
                    lay_popup_video.requestLayout()
                    lay_popup_video_border.clipScale = b
                    popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.isOn = true

                    lay_popup_video.clearAnimation()
                    lay_popup_video.startAnimation(loadAnimation(R.anim.fade_in).apply { duration = 150 })
                }

                lay_popup_video.clearAnimation()
                lay_popup_video.startAnimation(this)
            }
            return
        }
    }

    popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.isOn = true

    currPopupVideoAnim?.cancel()
    currPopupVideoAnim = AnimatorSet().apply {
        duration = 350L
        onStart {
            lay_popup_video.visible()
            Trace.d("Start Popup Video Animation")
        }
        playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lay_popup_video, "clipScale", lay_popup_video.clipScale, 1F),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lay_popup_video, "x", lay_popup_video.x, x),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lay_popup_video, "y", lay_popup_video.y, y),
                ValueAnimator.ofInt(layoutParam.width, w).apply {
                    addUpdateListener {
                        val animW = it.animatedValue as Int
                        layoutParam.width = animW
                        lay_popup_video.requestLayout()
                    }
                },
                ValueAnimator.ofInt(layoutParam.height, h).apply {
                    addUpdateListener {
                        val animH = it.animatedValue as Int
                        layoutParam.height = animH
                        lay_popup_video.requestLayout()
                    }
                },
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lay_popup_video_border, "clipScale", lay_popup_video_border.clipScale, b))

        start()
    }
}

fun closePopupVideo(anchor: PopupVideoAnchor) {
    if (popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.isOn?.not() != false) return

    popupVideoHolders[anchor]?.isOn = false
    if (anchor == PopupVideoAnchor.WEB && (popupVideoHolders[PopupVideoAnchor.QNA]?.isOn == true || popupVideoHolders[PopupVideoAnchor.POLL]?.isOn == true)) {
        return
    }

    val layoutParam = lay_popup_video.layoutParams

    for (popupVideoHolder in popupVideoHolders) {
        if (popupVideoHolder.value.isOn) {

            loadAnimation(R.anim.fade_out).apply {
                duration = 150
                onEnd {
                    lay_popup_video.clipScale = 1F
                    lay_popup_video.x = popupVideoHolder.value.x
                    lay_popup_video.y = popupVideoHolder.value.y
                    lay_popup_video.layoutParams.width = popupVideoHolder.value.w
                    lay_popup_video.layoutParams.height = ((popupVideoHolder.value.w.f / videoSize.w.f) * videoSize.h.f).i
                    lay_popup_video.requestLayout()
                    lay_popup_video_border.clipScale = if (popupVideoHolder.value.isBordered) .95F else 1F

                    lay_popup_video.clearAnimation()
                    lay_popup_video.startAnimation(loadAnimation(R.anim.fade_in).apply { duration = 150 })
                }

                lay_popup_video.clearAnimation()
                lay_popup_video.startAnimation(this)
            }
            return
        }
    }

    currPopupVideoAnim?.cancel()
    currPopupVideoAnim = AnimatorSet().apply {
        duration = 350L
        onEnd {
            findFragment(GameAVStreamFragment::class.java)?.returnPlayer()
            pv_popup.player = null
            lay_popup_video.invisible()
        }
        playTogether(
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lay_popup_video, "clipScale", lay_popup_video.clipScale, 3.5F),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lay_popup_video, "x", lay_popup_video.x, 0F),
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lay_popup_video, "y", lay_popup_video.y, 0F),
                ValueAnimator.ofInt(layoutParam.width, videoSize.w).apply {
                    addUpdateListener {
                        val animW = it.animatedValue as Int
                        layoutParam.width = animW
                        lay_popup_video.requestLayout()
                    }
                },
                ValueAnimator.ofInt(layoutParam.height, videoSize.h).apply {
                    addUpdateListener {
                        val animH = it.animatedValue as Int
                        layoutParam.height = animH
                        lay_popup_video.requestLayout()
                    }
                },
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(lay_popup_video_border, "clipScale", lay_popup_video_border.clipScale, 3.5F))

        start()
    }
}
```

And the `showPopupVideo()` above is mainly called in another Fragment, while `closePopupVideo()` is called when a 10-second timer is finished:

```
...
val streamFragment = findFragment(GameAVStreamFragment::class.java)
if (streamFragment?.isAudioOnly?.not() == true) {
    if (activity.popupVideoHolders[GamePlayActivity.PopupVideoAnchor.WEB]?.isOn == true) {
        activity.arrangeView(R.id.lay_popup_video, R.id.lay_qna)
    } else {
        activity.arrangeView(R.id.lay_head, R.id.lay_popup_video, R.id.lay_qna)
    }

    activity.showPopupVideo(GamePlayActivity.PopupVideoAnchor.QNA)
} else {
    vw_hole_cover.visible()
}
...
```

...might it be a threading issue?

Comment: [mcve] perhaps? The method returns null when the view cannot be found; so more details is needed to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: when the id you are looking for is not part of activity/fragment's view hierarchy (answering the question in the title)

Comment: I've just added the example above. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: You are asking in what situations `findViewById()`might return null. At which point in the example code you shared do you call `findViewById()`? Please add more code so we can reproduce the problem without patching the missing parts.

Comment: I completely forgot to mention that I was using the `kotlinx.android.synthetic` library, so that the call to the view's ID is automatically a cached `findViewById()` in itself.

Answer (score 1):

FindViewById may return null if the id given is not in your associated view. Or, if you're calling findviewbyid on a view group, the viewgroup doesn't hold the view that have the specific id.

Comment: That would be the usual case, yes. However, I've just added the example above. The view with that ID is in the layout.

Comment: Sorry, but inside your updated code, I didn't see findViewById anywhere

Comment: Oh, that's because I'm using the `kotlinx.synthetic` library which eliminates the need for that, though it still calls `findViewById` in the end. I forgot to specify that.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using id which is not available in XML layout in that case it will suddenly return null.

For e.g.

Layout(XML):

```
<TextView
    android:id="tv_sample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 />
```

Activity(Java):

```
Textview tvSample = findViewById(R.id.tv_sam);
```

Check the id's of declaring in layout and activity files, so that it will fire NullPointerException.